Differentiating regular expressions with squaring
Regular expressions describe languages with letters, and the operators +, . and *.
Given two languages L1 and L2 described by regular expressions, we can give an exponential upper bound on the size of the smaller word belonging to say L1, but not L2.
Now what if we also add the squaring operator ²?
Differentiating L1 and L2 is known to be EXPSPACE-complete, does that mean the best upper bound we can have on the size of the smaller word separating the languages is doubly exponential?
